# Elastic Java client returns different result from HTTP API

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have an application that is using the *Elasticsearch Java API (5.6.7)* to execute an aggregation query (terms). I have created the following search document using curl and the HTTP API (relevant information displayed):

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 0,
  "sort" : [
    {
      "@timestamp" : {
        "order" : "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggregations" : {
    "level" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "level.keyword",
        "size" : 10,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now that the query has been implemented in my Java program, I notice that the **results are different** from the HTTP API results!

Both return the *exact* same meta-information regarding shards, number of hits, etc:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3659,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": [

    ]
  }
```

However the returned aggregation from the Java API **does not contain** any buckets:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "level": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [

      ]
    }
```

while the same aggregation from the HTTP API **does** contain the buckets:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "level": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "INFO",
          "doc_count": 2691
        },
        {
          "key": "WARN",
          "doc_count": 776
        },
        {
          "key": "ERROR",
          "doc_count": 192
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am 100% sure that the search document is the same (copied it from the Java app log).

**Q: What can cause this difference?**

**EDIT** 
My java code for building the query is (contains a lot of references to other classes):

```
    // Start building the search itself
    SearchRequestBuilder srch = client.prepareSearch(indices.toArray(new String[indices.size()]))
            .setTypes(types.toArray(new String[types.size()])).setFrom(0).setSize(0);
    // Conditional sort order
    if (t.getOrder() != null)
        srch.addSort(t.getOrder().getBuilder());
    // Add aggregationbuilders to this search
    for (NivoStatistic stat : t.getStatistics())
    {
        logger.log(Level.FINER, "Adding statistic {0}", stat.getName());
        srch.addAggregation(stat.getContent());
    }
    // Use a search template    
    NivoQuery qry = t.getQuery();
    SearchTemplateRequestBuilder srchTemplate = new SearchTemplateRequestBuilder(client)
            .setRequest(srch.request())
            .setScript(qry.getTemplateString())
            .setScriptType(ScriptType.INLINE)
            .setScriptParams(qry.getParameterValues())
            ;
    logger.log(Level.FINER, "Prepared search: {0}", srchTemplate.request().getRequest().toString());
```

The output from the last log statement is what I use to POST via `curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/...`

Then execution is done via

```
    // Execute the search
    try
    {
        SearchResponse resp = srchTemplate.get().getResponse();
        logger.log(Level.FINER, "Search returned: {0}", resp.toString());
        if (resp.status() == RestStatus.OK && resp.getAggregations() != null)
        {
            for (Aggregation agg : resp.getAggregations().asList())
            {
                // Update response
                t.getResponse().addStat(new NivoStatsHit(agg));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ElasticsearchException e)
    {
        throw new ApiException(ApiExceptionCode.SEARCH_10061, "Database error: " + e.getDetailedMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how you're sending this via Java code vs curl?

Comment: @Val just added the Java code. Via curl, it's just sending the search document as POST content.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and print the query sent to elasticsearch via the java code?

Comment: @alkis the query printed from `logger.log(Level.FINER, "Prepared search: {0}", srchTemplate.request().getRequest().toString());` is the first code block in my question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, sorry, I missed it.

Comment: Where do you print what comes from the Java API? And what should this piece of code do? `for (Aggregation agg : resp.getAggregations().asList())
            {
                // Update response
                t.getResponse().addStat(new NivoStatsHit(agg));
            }`

Comment: To me so far this looks like you are doing something wrong when printing the results. But I don't think you shared the code that prints what you showed us so far, meaning the empty buckets list.

Comment: @AndreiStefan `resp.getAggregations()` returns a pre-configured list of aggregation builders that are used to build the elastic query. In the very last code block, I print the returned results using `logger.log(Level.FINER, "Search returned: {0}", resp.toString());`

Comment: So, you did make sure to compare the query you are sending via curl, with the actual JSON produced by the Java API, right? I assume that the first block is the query output generated by the Java API, and you just sent it via curl for trying out.

Comment: That is what I did, correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started testing your code with Elasticserach 5.6.3 and, while at first it looked doable, then I realized is not that easy. And all seems to boil down to search templates usage.

The main thing with your code is that you are using search templates combined with aggregations. In my tests, also, not even `size` and `from` worked ;-). Not sure how it worked for you though. Or maybe you haven't realized that the result is also getting you back the documents themselves, as it's not relevant from your post. The query you are logging looks right, indeed, but the results show that aggregations, `size` and `from` are ignored.

So, at this point I started looking into why search templates and aggregations don't seem to work (fyi, `resp.getAggregations()` returns `null`). And I found this - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22766.

I tried to combine a search template builder with a normal search request, but I failed.

Comment: Wow. The code was written for elastic 2.x and we recently upgraded to 5.x. I did have some issues with breaking changes but this looks as though it might not be resolvable. Do you have a suggestion as to the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not. I played with the code this morning for few tens of minutes, but didn't find/see a solution on how to combine both search templates and aggregations in Java API. Of course they are possible with the usual `curl` commands, but I didn't see a way out with Java code. Maybe you can find something, but at least now you know there might be issues on this area, as indicated by that GH issue I referenced.